# Использование сокетов в разных сетях python

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

Итак. У меня есть код, которые работает с сокетами на python и осуществляет связь между сервером и клиентом. Проблема в том, что это работает только тогда, когда сервер и клиент находятся в одной сети. Как я могу настроить программу, чтобы она не зависела от сети? То есть, клиент подключается к какому-то ip и отправляет ему данные, и сервер тоже может отправлять данные клиенту; при этом они подключены к разным сетям, может даже в разных странах...

Я нашел похожий вопрос, и вот ответ на него: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45256338/11455396. Но это не очень помогло мне.

Comment: Собственно, ответ уже написан по вашей ссылке - сервер должен находиться в сети с публичным IP-адресом.

Comment: server должен слушает 0.0.0.0, плюс нужно настроить на компе с сервером чтобы не было блокировки по порту (firewall), а у роутера настроить проброс порта к компу с серверу. Тогда запрос по публичному ip приведет к роутеру, а тот по номеру порта прокинет запрос к компу с сервером

Comment: Не могли бы вы подробнее объяснить, как сделать "чтобы не было блокировки по порту (firewall), а у роутера настроить проброс порта к компу с серверу". Я просто не очень разбираюсь в таких вещах